# Did galaxies spin differently 4, 5, 6 billion years ago?

Tags: cosmology, gravity, dark-matter

Today I read that the [Matter-dominated era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)) ended 4 billion years ago, and now we're in the Dark Energy dominated era.

Obviously, light from galaxies far enough away would be from earlier in the [chronology of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe). For example, the [Abell 370](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abell_370) cluster is 5 billion light years away.

Is there a before / after period where galaxies behave differently?

Comment: Are you confusing Dark Energy with Dark Matter? It is Dark Matter that causes stars in galaxies to rotate as they do.  As far as I know Dark Energy only affects the expansion of space (not the rotation of galaxies.)